# Filter a range number in Query Builder of QGIS 2.8.6

Tags: qgis, query, filter

I need to filter features that have attributes that start within a relative number range. I am using brackets to filter the range of numbers, but it does not work me. This is my query:

```
CASE
WHEN  "nombre"  like '[0-3]%' THEN 'ROSETAS'
WHEN  "nombre"  like '[4-5]%' THEN 'CTO'
ELSE 'OTRAS'
END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `regexp_match` function to match the first number inside your `CASE` statements:

```
CASE
WHEN regexp_match("nombre", '^[0-3].*') THEN 'ROSETAS'
WHEN regexp_match("nombre", '^[4-5].*') THEN 'CTO'
ELSE 'OTRAS'
END
```

Comment: @jfaneca - Haha most welcome =)